# Block path in config.xml

Tags: magento

Let say I have a module which is the name Metro_Most_Viewed. The module configuration file config.xml reside in the `/local/Metro/Most_Viwed/etc` directory.

As you know, all directory seperator "/" will replace underscore character. So, I would like to know, how can we write a class name such a directory?

For instance :
Metro_Most_Viewed_Block

equivalent = /app/code/local/Metro/Most_Viewed/Block
is that right?

Or, do you have an alternate method to make folder name like "Most-Viewed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to name it MostViewed in order to be a valid module name.

Comment: No I don't think its possible.

Comment: Magento Core does two words using the FirstSecond syntax, eg. `CatalogIndex`, `CatalogSearch`, `XmlConnect`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer module name to be like: **Mostviewed** (only first letter capital) instead of **MostViewed**.